# Select files in specific folders

Tags: powershell

In my script i run once`$data = gci d:\ -recurse -force` then i use the output for different purposes like  files or folders reports, so it is not possible to filter main gci command with `Where-Object`. Now for a specific table i need to retrieve files from my $data output in directory specified by user via a function parameter. Here what i use for folders :

```
$regexPath = [regex]::Escape($SpecificDirectory)
$folders = $data | ? {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory" -and $_.FullName -match "^$regexPath"}
```

But i have no idea how can use the output of my $Data variable to get files from   a specific folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get files the same way you get folders, only that you invert the check for the object type (from `-eq "Directory"` to `-ne "Directory"`).

I'd recommend some optimizations, though:

- Using the `PSIsContainer` property is an easier way to distinguish between filees and folders.
- Pattern matching (operator `-like`) provides better performance than regular expression matching (operator `-match`).

Try something like this:

```
$data | ? {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.FullName -like "$SpecificDirectory\*"}
```

If you want only the files in `$SpecificDirectory`, not its subdirectories, you could also do something like this:

```
$data | ? {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.DirectoryName -eq $SpecificDirectory}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for but the following will provide you with all of the files in the d:\temp\vm folder:

$data = gci d:\ -recurse -force

$data | Where { $_.DirectoryName -like "D:\temp\vm" }